# How to show zero value instead of blank in table visualization Power BI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery

I would like to ask for your assistance if there's a possible measures or settings to make blank cells into zero value in table visuals. Here's the table and I only use 1 table for this.

[image: Table Chart Visual]

[image: Table fields]

Already tried to use "COALESCE" measure

Comment: Read: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/how-to-return-0-instead-of-blank-in-dax/